# PHP mPDF with cut command - printing too much paper

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have a printer receipt called "Start STP 100" and my website creates a PDF with a receipt format using the mPDF library.

The following code is my class to generate a PDF:

```
class printdoc
{
    private $width;

    public function __construct()
    {
        require('mPDF/mpdf.php');

        $this->width = 80;

        // Default values
        $this->mPDF = new mPDF('utf-8', array($this->width, 1000), 9, 'Segoe UI', 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 'P');
        $this->mPDF->setAutoTopMargin = 'pad';
    }

    public function write($html, $url)
    {
        $this->mPDF->WriteHTML($html[0]);
        $this->mPDF->page   = 0;
        $this->mPDF->state  = 0;
        unset($this->mPDF->pages[0]);

        $p = 'P';
        // At this point the Y size is set according to the dimensions of the PDF
        // So the value '1000' set in the __construct() has no effect.
        $this->mPDF->_setPageSize(array($this->width, $this->mPDF->y), $p);

        foreach($html as $content)
        {
            $this->mPDF->addPage();
            $this->mPDF->WriteHTML($content);
        }

        $this->mPDF->Output($url);
    }

    public function create($data)
    {
        $html  = '<html>';
        $html .= '  <head></head>';
        $html .= '  <body>';
        $html .=        $this->header($data);
        $html .=        $this->body($data);
        $html .=        $this->footer($data);
        $html .= '  </body>';
        $html .= '</html>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Now in order to create the receipt and save it, I have this function:

```
function printreceipt($data)
{
    require('printdoc.php');

    $file = 'test-receipt.pdf';
    $html = $this->printdoc->create($data);

    $this->printdoc->write($html, $file);
}
```

What happens is that the file generated when seen with Chrome PDF Viewer has the correct dimensions (in terms of width and height), but when sent to the printer it prints too much paper.

Basically this is the size of the PDF (when viewed on a browser):

```
 ---
|   |
|   |
|   |
 ---
```

And this is the size of the paper when printed:

```
 ---
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
 ---
```

Is there any way to force mPDF to cut the file or write any command after my `html` in order to the printer interpret and cut?

Comment: while viewing the PDF how many pages your getting??

Comment: did you checked that one???

Comment: @kranthi only one page even if the receipt has 100 or 500 height. It's dynamic and it only creates one page.

Comment: can you please check one by printing html and is there any feasabilty  to provide HTML and pdf link???

Comment: @kranthi I don't get it. You want me to create a test page and print random HTML to see if the printer cuts?

Comment: yes.. and please provide PDF

Comment: @kranthi seems a good test to me. I don't have the printer with me right now, but I'm gonna create the code and paste into the topic.

Comment: dont print here that .... just create a file with PDF html  and provide a link

Comment: @kranthi hey man, I manage to get in touch with printer supplier and it seems it's a chrome related issue. In firefox the document is well printed. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Start STP 100 has a bug with Google Chrome that created extra paper.
Using firefox solved the issue.

> Please note that the preview for receipts from a Star printer is almost always wrong, showing an extremely long run of receipt paper. Please disregard this, you will be safe to print.

https://www.websitesupport.info/hc/en-us/articles/205959070-Setting-Up-Chrome-For-Windows-To-Print-From-The-Rain-Point-Of-Sale